# Endlessly animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Please tell me how should I use setInterval or whatever what will help me to execute function forever:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PaVOxM

```
$(document).ready(function (doStuff){


$( '.main-moto2').hide()
$( '.main-moto3').hide()

// fade in: duration 1s on complete call function
$( '.main-moto' ).fadeIn(3000, function(){

    // fade out: duration 1s, on complete call function
    $( '.main-moto' ).fadeOut(3000, function(){

    // fade in: duration 1s
    $( '.main-moto2' ).fadeIn(1000)
    $( '.main-moto2' ).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $( '.main-moto3' ).fadeIn(1000)
    $( '.main-moto3' ).fadeOut(1000)




    });
```

Comment: Drop the jQuery, use a CSS animation.

Comment: May I ask why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, good point.  :-)  The main reason is that the browser will optimize for the animation and handle it for you.  Rather than jQuery firing some JavaScript with `requestAnimationFrame`, the browser will just take care of it.  More efficient.  The other reason is that you won't have this jQuery dependency and it will simplify your code a bit.

Comment: Thank you for info. Nevertheless I'd like to know how to do this work with jquery. It is a matter of learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var index = -1, isUpdateIndex = true;
var arrDivs = [{ className: ".main-moto", timeout: 3000 }, { className: ".main-moto2", timeout: 1000 }, { className: ".main-moto3", timeout: 1000 }];

$(document).ready(function (doStuff){
  // hide all divs
  $('.main-moto, .main-moto2, .main-moto3').hide();
  customFade();
});

function customFade() {
  if (isUpdateIndex) {
    index = (index + 1) % arrDivs.length;
  }
  isUpdateIndex = !isUpdateIndex;
  $(arrDivs[index].className).fadeToggle(arrDivs[index].timeout, customFade);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = 'main-moto'>
 <div class = 'wrap'>
  <div class = 'main-moto-text'>
  main-moto<br>
 <div class ='yellow-block'> <span style="color: rgb(248, 184, 38);">Саша</span><br></div>
  по шоссе
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = 'main-moto2'>
 <div class = 'wrap'>
  <div class = 'main-moto-text'>
 main-moto2 <br>
 <div class ='yellow-block'> <span style="color: rgb(248, 184, 38);">сосала</span> сушку</div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = 'main-moto3'>
 <div class = 'wrap'>
  <div class = 'main-moto-text'>
  main-moto3 <br>
 <div class ='yellow-block'> <span style="color: rgb(248, 184, 38);">реку, видит грека в реке </span> рак</div>  
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```